# Is there a function in golang for reading information emitted inside the events?

Tags: go, events, ethereum, blockchain, go-ethereum

I'm new to golang and can`t find the answer.

I have a simple golang package that should parse the amount of blocks to find there emitted events and use information from those events later.

I already have logs of type `[]ethTypes.Log` returned by function FetchEventLogs() from go-ethereum package:

```
logs, err := client.FetchEventLogs(ctx, contractAddress, string(EventSig), startBlock, endBlock)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

but I don`t know how to parse these logs into a struct.

For example, my event sig is "MyEvent(uint8,bytes32,uint64,address,bytes,bytes)".

I want to receive result that will be represented as a struct with all the emitted data

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to generate Go bindings based on your specific contract's ABI (Application Binary Interface) using the `abigen` tool that you can install as follows:

```
go get github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata/...
go get github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/abigen
```

Then you should be able to generate bindings out of your `.abi` file:

```
abigen --abi path/to/YourContract.abi --pkg somecontract --out YourContract.go
```

Note that you can generate your contract ABI using Solidity compiler as:

```
solc --abi YourContract.sol
```

You can then import your Go generated bindings `somecontract` package and define a `struct` where you would parse your `MyEvent` log event in:

package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "yourmodulepath/somecontract"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

// Define a struct to represent the event data
type MyEvent struct {
    Field1 uint8
    Field2 [32]byte
    Field3 uint64
    Field4 common.Address
    Field5 []byte
    Field6 []byte
}

func main() {
    // ...
    // Fetch the event logs
    logs, err := client.FetchEventLogs(ctx, contractAddress, string(EventSig), startBlock, endBlock)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Iterate over the logs and parse the event data
    for _, log := range logs {
        var event MyEvent

        err := somecontract.UnpackLog(&event, "MyEvent", log)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Access the event data in the struct
        fmt.Println("Field1:", event.Field1)
        fmt.Println("Field2:", event.Field2)
        fmt.Println("Field3:", event.Field3)
        fmt.Println("Field4:", event.Field4.Hex())
        fmt.Println("Field5:", event.Field5)
        fmt.Println("Field6:", event.Field6)
    }
}
```